# Why isn't my js able to access css properties from external css using js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I don't add style(visibility) in style-menu tag, it won't work. Otherwise when style(visibility) is added it works.

(file.html)

```
<div class="share-menu" id="share-menu" style = "visibility: hidden;">

                <div class="facebook">Facebook</div>
                <div class="whatsapp">WhatsApp</div>
                <div class="twitter">Twitter</div>
                <div class="telegram">Telegram</div>
                <div class="linkedin">Linkedin</div>

            </div>
```

(file.js)

```
let shareBtn = document.getElementById("share-btn");
let shareMenu = document.getElementById("share-menu");

shareBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
         if(shareMenu.style.visibility == "hidden"){
            shareMenu.style.visibility = "visible";
        }else if(shareMenu.style.visibility == "visible"){
            shareMenu.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        });
```

(file.css)

```
.share-menu{
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
top: 80px;
width: 140px;
height: max-content;
display: flex;
visibility: hidden;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 7px 7px 15px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: CSS rules do not affect the "style" objects on DOM elements. The "style" objects are only for style properties directly in the HTML.

Comment: To get the styles that come from CSS files, you have to use [`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. I wanted to ask that can I access css rules using example.style method directly without using some getComputedStyle method.